# How to use Bloom Filter with AWS Elasticache (Redis)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, redis, bloom-filter

How to use Bloom Filter module in AWS Elasticache redis, for a local setup importing the module can help solve th issue, but I am not sure how can I use a Bloom Filter package like rebloom(https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rebloom) in AWS Elasticache.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. But you if you get a Managed Redis from RedisLabs you are getting it built in.

See: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/vpc/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Redisson](https://redisson.org)'s implementation of Bloom Filter. It works with any Redis vendor.

```
RBloomFilter<SomeObject> bloomFilter = redisson.getBloomFilter("sample");
// initialize bloom filter with 
// expectedInsertions = 55000000
// falseProbability = 0.03
bloomFilter.tryInit(55000000L, 0.03);

bloomFilter.add(new SomeObject("field1Value", "field2Value"));
bloomFilter.add(new SomeObject("field5Value", "field8Value"));

bloomFilter.contains(new SomeObject("field1Value", "field8Value"));
bloomFilter.count();
```

Comment: Nikita - is this even possible to do over AWS elasticache? dosent it require actual redis implementation for the bloom filter ?

Comment: No, Redisson uses own implementation.